# Splitting a report into separate emails with their individual reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to send separate Employees a PDF/page of their section/report. The information is based on their EmployeeID (which is text not long number). So each person has their balance information on a page then there's a page break, and then next page shows the next person's details. With the code below, it does email each of the employees one page but it so happens to only email the first person's page to EVERYONE. Is it possible to somehow automate each week so that each user is emailed his/her individual page of the report?

Another error is that the email pop up one by one so I have to press send each time for over 200 people, and that the email seems to be sending to the email but then followed by #mailto:the email# for example email@email.com#mailto:email@email.com#

I just started Access and have been copying and scraping code off of places I have found online. Many thanks in advance, if you can assist!

Have a great day!

```
Private Sub cmdSendAll_Click()

Dim rsAccountNumber As DAO.Recordset
Dim strTo As Variant
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMessageText As String

Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, [Email] FROM [queAutoUpdate]", dbOpenSnapshot)

Debug.Print strTo

With rsAccountNumber

Do Until .EOF

DoCmd.OpenReport "test", _
acViewPreview, _
WhereCondition:="EmployeeID = '" & !EmployeeID & "'", _
WindowMode:=acHidden

strTo = ![Email]
strSubject = "Updated Balance "
strMessageText = "Text Here"


DoCmd.SendObject ObjectType:=acSendReport, _
ObjectName:="test", _
OutputFormat:=acFormatPDF, _
To:=strTo, _
Subject:=strSubject, _
MESSAGETEXT:=strMessageText, _
EditMessage:=True


DoCmd.Close acReport, "Unaffirmed Report", acSaveNo


.MoveNext

Loop

.Close

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opening a report called test and then closing another report called "Unaffirmed Report". You need to open and close the same report, in this case "test".
`DoCmd.Close acReport, "test", acSaveNo`. This should fix the employee data not updating, since the report remains open on the first employee.

To directly send the message you need change `EditMessage:=True` to `EditMessage:=False`.
Check the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.sendobject

Also if you need to test this, set outlook in Offline mode, and run your code, check the messages in your Outbox to see if they're as expected. You can delete the messages from the Outbox to prevent them from being sent. Once you're finished with testing you can set Outlook back to Online Mode.

Regarding the email address issue, this comes automatically when using hyperlinks in your controls. You'll need to strip the extra part out with `strTo = Left(![Email],InStr(![Email],"#")-1)`. Check your data if this will be valid for all email addresses. For a more advanced solution you can look at this post https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-hyperlink-data-type.

Code provided as reference, please see the post for the explanation.

```
'copied from https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-hyperlink-data-type

Public Function GetHyperlinkFullAddress(ByVal hyperlinkData As Variant, Optional ByVal removeMailto As Boolean) As Variant

    Const SEPARATOR As String = "#"

    Dim retVal As Variant
    Dim tmpArr As Variant

    If IsNull(hyperlinkData) Then
        retVal = hyperlinkData
    Else

        If InStr(hyperlinkData, SEPARATOR) > 0 Then
            ' I append 4 separators at the end, so I don't have to worry about the
            ' lenght of the array returned by Split()
            hyperlinkData = hyperlinkData & String(4, SEPARATOR)
            tmpArr = Split(hyperlinkData, SEPARATOR)

            If Len(tmpArr(1)) > 0 Then
                retVal = tmpArr(1)
                If Len(tmpArr(2)) > 0 Then
                    retVal = retVal & "#" & tmpArr(2)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            retVal = hyperlinkData
        End If

        If Left(retVal, 7) = "mailto:" Then
            retVal = Mid(retVal, 8)
        End If

    End If

    GetHyperlinkFullAddress = retVal

End Function
```

Comment: You my good sir/ma'am are brilliant! The only problem is that now there is a pop up that says "A program is trying to send an email message onyour behalf... " then click "allow"... unfortunately due to company policies I cannot change the programmatic access security on my trust center in outlook...
But again YOU ARE AMAZING! Thank you!

Comment: Yes using `DoCmd.SendObjects` will give you that issue. I believe if you use the other solution suggested by Parfait, using the Outlook Object model to send the email, then you'll not get the popup.

Comment: thanks jbud! When using the above code I run into some compile errors

Comment: Where are your getting the issue? I think you'll need to create a new question for this. There might be others with different ideas on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the MS Outlook object library to send emails. Whereas `DoCmd.SendObject` is a convenience handler, you control more of the process with initializing an Outlook application object and creating an Outlook email object setting all needed elements.

However, with this approach you need to first export your filtered report to PDF and then attach to email for final send. See inline comments for specific details.

```vb
Dim rsAccountNumber As DAO.Recordset
' CHECK Microsoft Outlook #.# Object Library UNDER Tools/References
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fileName As string, todayDate As String, strEmail As String    

todayDate = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")

Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID, [Email] FROM [queAutoUpdate]", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

With rsAccountNumber
     Do Until .EOF
         ' SETTING FILE NAME TO SAME PATH AS DATABASE (ADJUST AS NEEDED)
         fileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Balance_Report_" & !EmployeeID & "_" & todayDate & ".pdf"

         ' OPEN AND EXPORT PDF TO FILE 
         DoCmd.OpenReport "test", acViewPreview, "EmployeeID = '" & !EmployeeID & "'"
         ' INTENTIONALLY LEAVE REPORT NAME BLANK FOR ABOVE FILTERED REPORT
         DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, , acFormatPDF, fileName, False
         DoCmd.Close acReport, "test" 

         ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT
         strEmail = ![Email]
         Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
         With olEmail
             .Recipients.Add strEmail
             .Subject = "Updated Balance"
             .Body = "Text Here"
             .Attachments.Add fileName           ' ATTACH PDF REPORT
             .Send                               ' SEND WITHOUT DISPLAY TO SCREEN
         End With 

         Set olEmail = Nothing
         .MoveNext
     Loop
     .Close
End With

MsgBox "All emails successfully sent!", vbInformation, "EMAIL STATUS"

Set rsAccountNumber = Nothing: Set olApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait! (Sorry a friend suggested that I exported the list to Excel then use Mail merge in Word...) I tried your code but it seems to get a compile error: variable not defined at "CurrentDb"

Comment: Hmmm...that's your line not mine. Also, tell your friend MS Access can run mail merge. And the very engine for Office mail merge uses the Access engine!